# How do you increase Interlink level?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

In combat, my Interlink level seems to slowly increase. However, I can't see any gauge or meter that tracks how close it is to the next level, nor do I have any indication of how to increase that level. From what I've gathered so far, being in combat will make it go up slowly, but I'm wondering:

- if both members need to be alive to increase it
- if canceling arts makes it go up faster
- if using fusion arts makes it go up faster
- if having both members be the same role, or different roles, affects the rate of increase

Really, I'm just wondering what makes it go up faster. How does this mechanic work?

Answer (score 2):

The Interlink level tip in-game says that it can be increased by fusion arts. It doesn't say anything else can increase it, so it is probably the only thing that does.

Comment: This is really strange, as my NPC party members seem to get to Interlink 3 within seconds of the battle starting, so there's no way it's just fusion arts. Unless the AI is cheating, which I suppose is entirely possible.

Comment: I was wondering the same, and after getting the loading tip, I run some tests. It apparently takes 3 fused art use to increase rank by 1. but, i'm strongly under the impression that both partners fused art count.